# How can I change the number of recent sites on the Home Tab page?

Tags: google-chrome

In the Google Chrome Home Tab page, there are two sections, **Apps** and **Most visited**.

How can I increase the number of sites that show up on the **Most visited** section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need a Chrome extension like

[Speed Dial](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/speed-dial/dgpdioedihjhncjafcpgbbjdpbbkikmi),

or

[Speed Dial 2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/speed-dial-2/jpfpebmajhhopeonhlcgidhclcccjcik)

Otherwise you may just prefer to use some cloud based offering like

[myfav.es](http://www.myfav.es/fast)

You can find a good review of the available options on [LifeHacker](http://lifehac.kr/AfLUIG)

Comment: Something is wrong with the store links, but I think I get the idea. Thanks.